# How to view users of Azure SQL Database server, using Azure Console?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have created a Azure database server using Azure portal. During the creation, I had provided a user and password. I have also created a Azure Database inside this Server. I am now trying to connect to this Database from MS SSMS, however I have forgotten this user name and password. I would like to know how I can view this user name and also reset the password from Azure console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow steps provided below:

1. Using Azure Portal open your Azure SQL Server blade (do not confuse with the database blade)
2. Make sure you are in the Overview blade.
3. Click on "Reset password" at the top of the overview blade.
4. Set the new password and click save.

[image]

**References:**
[Reset lost admin account password](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/07/23/reset-lost-admin-account-password/)

Comment: I did see this option, but I would like to know how do I view a list of users.  Is it that only one user (admin) can be associated with the SQL server (not database) ?. The SQL database creation wizard didn't ask me for any users.

Comment: Here you will see how to create users https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Ok. It seems, I can create, view etc. users, through SSMS only, and not from the Azure Console.

Comment: This thread shows you how to list user logins https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185227/determine-databases-specified-login-has-access-to-on-sql-azure/185239#185239

Comment: I think you can use the Query Editor also from the Portal https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/t-sql-query-editor-in-browser-azure-portal/